# Batch File: If-Else statment and trying to check for incorrect input

Tags: batch-file

I've never coded with batch before and I'm trying to make a very simple program, I'm not trying to create a program to actually do something like batch files are intended to, but the general idea is to create a very simple text exploration thing.

Here's the section of code I'm having trouble with,

```
:CLASSIFIED
cls
echo Please enter your credentials
echo.

:USERNAME
set /p loginInput=Login:
IF %loginInput%== smccauley goto PASSWORD

:PASSWORD
set /p passInput=Password:
IF %passInput%== password goto ACCESSGRANTED
```

What I need to happen is that if the user inputs something other than the exactly correct username and password, IE smccauley and password, it will say something along the lines of "Incorrect username or password, please re-enter your credentials," like this,

```
echo Incorrect username or password, please re-enter your credentials.
pause
goto CLASSIFIED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...
:USERNAME
set /p loginInput=Login:

:PASSWORD
set /p passInput=Password:
IF "%passInput%"=="password" IF "%loginInput%"=="smccauley" goto ACCESSGRANTED
echo Incorrect username or password, please re-enter your credentials.
pause
goto CLASSIFIED
```

Since you have uncontrolled input, it's possible for he user to supply any string - and that stringmay be empty or may contain spaces and other separators. `"quoting the string"` or variable gives some protection (it's not bullt-proof)

Cascading the tests provides an `and` function; if both are passed, go to the destination, otherwise produce the error message;wait and allow another attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
IF %loginInput%== smccauley goto PASSWORD
```

If you want this to say something, such as incorrect, on the next line add

```
else goto INCORRECT
```

In the incorrect variable, add in

```
echo Incorrect password. Please try again
wait(15)
goto CLASSIFIED
```